# How to convert mysql query in to dataframe

Tags: pandas

How to convert my sql query to data frame

column names of `PRODUCT` data frame
`user_id,status,actual_cost,selling_price`

Mysql query

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as Count FROM PRODUCT WHERE status = 'SOLD' AND actual_cost>50 AND selling_price>60
group by user_id
```

Disclaimer. Please don't tell to use `pymsql` or `pandassql` since groupby is very large >50K rows, Data base wont have that TTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```py
PRODUCT.query("status == 'SOLD' 
    and actual_cost > 50 
    and selling_price > 60").groupby('user_id').size().reset_index(name='Count')
```